# Color coding in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a table in excel that is color coded.

If the "type" of a certain item is "IT", then the whole row should be on color RED.
If the "type" of a certain item is "FU", then the whole row should be on color YELLOW.
If the "type" of a certain item is "GE", then the whole row should be on color VIOLET.

I would like this to be coded using macro and the trigger is every time I open the sheet.

Is this doable? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need a macro. Look up conditional formatting.

Comment: I tried doing that, but my problem is how can excel know that my condition is on another cell? For example, I've selected cells b1,c1,d1. And if cell A1 contains the value "IT", they should be colored with red. I don't know how to point the conditional formatting in A1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your area of working, suppose your cell is E2 that contain the text "IT"
2. Create a new formatting rule by clicking Conditional Formatting > New Rule... on the Home tab.
3. Select rule:  =SEARCH then formula like this =SEARCH("IT", $E2)>0
4. Click the "Format..." button and switch to Fill tab to choose the background color.

Comment: I've selected columns C7:L7 (which is the cells I would like to change) then clicked on conditional formatting > new rule. There is no rule such as =search, so I then click "Use a formula to determine which cell to format" (I'm using excel 2010). Then Typed this at the formula bar =SEARCH("IT", $B7)>0. Nothing happened.

Comment: hey, it worked. =SEARCH("IT", $B$7)>0 is what I wrote. Is it possible to put an "IF" statement? because if the word is not "IT" then it should not color the cells. If it is FU or GE, it should be on yellow or violet. Thanks!